# Suppress page header when subreport's group header appear

Tags: crystal-reports

there!

I'm stuck with suppressing page headers in Crystal Reports. Report layout:

- Main report:

  - 2 page headers
  - 2 subreports in details, each in separate section
  - grouping by one field
- sub reports layout:

  - report header section
  - details header section
  - 4 groups, in the 4-th I have header
  - report footer section (suppressed)

What I'm trying to aim is to hide page header when group header is appearing.

I tried to use shared variables: I set it to true in subreport's group header, to false in subreport's footer section and use it as condition in page header on the main report. But it doesn't work and it prints two headers: page header and group header.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

[Report example](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/3635ac00), on 8 page is example of the problem when two headers appear.

Comment: if in subreport group header is appearing then you want to supress main report page header? Is this your requirement

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want to do.

Comment: when do you require group header and when do you require page header.. I mean in first page or any specific condition where only one exists.. can you mention that condition

Comment: Group header should be shown after details section rendered as it has header for totals. When details section is rendered should shown page header.

Comment: I am sorry to say still can't get your requirement.. would try to answer perfectly if you can provide some screenshot.

Comment: I've added example of report outcome.

Comment: To the extent I see the attachment there is no need for the header after **total**. I don't know your intention in creating header but if you don't require you can remove that as it is unnecessary creating problems

Comment: No, I do need total header because it contains "Total" label. And don't need page header above total label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have found solution of my problem. It is very simple:
In the sub report for group I insert one header in the group header and total header in the group footer. Then I go to Group Expert-> My Group -> Options -> Options tab -> Set "Repeat Group Header On Each Page" to true. And remove page header from Main Report.

Answer (score -1):

Create a shared variable in sub report and assign a value to it and use the same variable in sub report and main report.

In sub report

```
shared numbervar a;
a:=1
```

in group header supress condition

```
Shared numbervar a;

if a=1
then true
else false
```

in main report page header superss section

```
Shared numbervar a;

if a=1
then false
else true
```

Comment: This is incorrect for a few reasons. The first is that you never set your numbervar back to 0 so after the first subreport, `a=1` forever, which suppresses every single page header. Second (the big problem), a page header's suppression formula is evaluated _before_ any subreports on that same page so you cannot set a shared variable and then conditionally suppress the same page header.

Comment: Let the user tell whether the answer is correct or wrong. next coming to my answer **I have asked user about the condition he is using** but there is delay in his response so to give an idea I have answered as a example so that he can change it and use as answer. Let user tell what he needs.. also if you think my answer is wrong try to provide the correct answer to the user.. instead of voting down explaining the defects in the posted answer.

Comment: The purpose of the voting system is for community feedback. In this case, the downvote is because the solution you provided objectively does not work and is unlikely to be salvageable with minor edits. Nothing personal! Just try to check the validity of your answers beforehand.